# gdb stops program when I break at an address while it works with an offset

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, x86-64

I'm using GNU gdb (GDB) 8.3 on Kali Linux Rolling 2019.2. I have the following C code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int x = 5;
    int y = 3;
}
```

And assembly

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000001125 <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x0000000000001126 <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000000000001129 <+4>:     mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14],edi
   0x000000000000112c <+7>:     mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20],rsi
   0x0000000000001130 <+11>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x5
   0x0000000000001137 <+18>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x3
   0x000000000000113e <+25>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000000000001143 <+30>:    pop    rbp
   0x0000000000001144 <+31>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

When I break at a memory address, the program stops.

```
(gdb) break *0x0000000000001130
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1130
(gdb) r
Starting program: /root/Documents/soQuestionProgram 

[1]+  Stopped                 gdb soQuestionProgram
```

However, when I break at the same memory address using an offset of `main`, the breakpoint works.

```
(gdb) break *main+11
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1130
(gdb) r
Starting program: /root/Documents/soQuestionProgram 

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000555555555130 in main ()
```

Why does this happen, and how would I make breaking at a memory address work?

Comment: Not sure why it's stopped (that's usually a background job thingy) but due to PIE and ASLR the address you are using is just an offset and not the correct memory address hence it won't work. You can stop at the first instruction then disassemble or otherwise determine correct address. You can see in your last line, the actual address for that run is `0x0000555555555130`.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that. How would I find the actual address then for a line?

Comment: As I said, that's only established once the process is started. Hence use `starti` to do that, then you can use disassembly or some other method depending on your circumstances to get the correct address. Sounds like an XY problem though, you should tell us **why** you want to use addresses instead of line numbers or symbols.

Comment: To run and stop in `main`, use `start`.  Using `starti` will stop in the very first instruction in user-space, at the process entry point in `_start` which eventually calls main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, the address you are using in the first case is incorrect, probably due to something like PIE (GDB usually disables ASLR if it can).  This means you are trying to place a breakpoint at an invalid address, which is triggering a GDB bug that was fixed recently:

https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2019-05/msg00361.html

Once you see GDB stopped like this:

```
  [1]+  Stopped                 gdb soQuestionProgram
```

you should be dropped back to a shell.  Just resume GDB with the `fg` command and continue your debug session.  Once GDB 8.4 is out this bug will be fixed.

---

Use the GDB `start` or `starti` command to run the program but stop at the top of `main` or before the first instruction in userspace, respectively.  Once the program is running, GDB will have real addresses in its disassembly, not just relative offsets relative to the start of the file.

Or compile+link with `gcc -fno-pie -no-pie` to build a non-PIE executable with a fixed load address selected at link time.

Comment: Yes GDB disables ASLR, but `0x0000000000001130` is still relative to the base address (start of the executable file).  Disabling ASLR just fixes the base address at `0x005555555...` or something.  You can't get the executable mapped to the zero page.